# Native insert with null value causes SQLSyntaxErrorException ora-00932 inconsistent datatypes

Tags: spring, oracle, hibernate

I have a special case in my project, where I need to execute native insert into oracle db. But I have a problem, when an inserting value (in column b in my example) is null - this exception occures:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got BINARY
```

I think hibernate cannot correctly set inserted datatype, when the value is null. How can I insert null value with native insert?

My JPA repository:

```
public interface MyRepository extends JpaRepository<MyTable, MyTablePk>, QueryDslPredicateExecutor<MyTable> {

    @Modifying
    @Transactional
    @Query(value = "INSERT INTO DATA.MY_TABLE (a, b, c, d, e) "
            + "VALUES(?1, ?2, ?3, ?4, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)", nativeQuery = true)
    void insertData(String a, 
            BigDecimal b, 
            Integer c, 
            Integer d);
}
```

Db table:

```
create table DATA.my_table (
    a varchar2(10 char) not null,
    b number(10,8),
    c number(2,0) not null,
    d number(4,0) not null,
    e timestamp,
  constraint my_table_pk primary key (a, c, d)
);
```

Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "DATA")
public class MyTable implements Serializable  {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6802433470917268375L;

    @Id
    private MyTablePk id;

    @Column(precision=10, scale=8)
    private BigDecimal b;  

    @NotNull
    @Column(nullable = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date e;  
...
```

Env: Java 8, Spring 4.1.4, Hibernate 4.3.7.Final, Oracle 12c.

Thank you